# Formarray validation and disable next button angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want validation for my checkbox in angular4. Like i have two checkboxes which i am generating using formarray via reactive forms and if none is selected i need to disable my next button.

Thanks for the help

```js
totalAccounts = [
        {numOfAccounts:1, id:1, accountName:"CHECKING ACCOUNT - ACCOUNT 1"}, 
        {numOfAccounts:1, id:2, accountName:"MONEY MARKET ACCOUNT - ACCOUNT 2"}
    ];

let accountsArray = [];
        for (let account of this.totalAccounts) {
            accountsArray.push(this.formBuild.group({
            isChosen: [true, Validators.required],
            numOfAccounts:[account.numOfAccounts, Validators.required],
            accountName: [account.accountName, Validators.required],
            id:account.id,
            accountValueText: "Number of accounts to open:",
          }));
        } 
        this.accountSetup = this.formBuild.group({
            accountList: this.formBuild.array(accountsArray)
        });
```

```html
<form *ngIf="accountSetup" [formGroup]="accountSetup" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="page col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="padding:3%;" formArrayName="accountList">
                <div *ngFor="let account of accountList.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline citi-checkbox" style="font-family: 'Interstate', sans-serif; font-size: 20px">
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChosen" (click)="checked()" /> {{account.controls.accountName.value}}   
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <p style="padding-left:22px;">
                            {{account.controls.accountValueText.value}}
                        <input class="form-control" formControlName="numOfAccounts" placeholder="Enter" style="width:100px;">
                    </p><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="page col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <nav aria-label="...">
                    <ul class="pager">
                        <button type="button" class="previous" (click)="goToPreviousPage()">Previous</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="next" [disabled]="accountSetup.invalid">Next</button>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix you can set a new field on totalAccounts and set its value on clicks. Then set the button disabled if they are false.

```
totalAccounts = [
        {numOfAccounts:1, id:1, accountName:"CHECKING ACCOUNT - ACCOUNT 1", checked: false}, 
        {numOfAccounts:1, id:2, accountName:"MONEY MARKET ACCOUNT - ACCOUNT 2", checked: false}
]
```

HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" #check formControlName="isChosen" (click)="checked(); totalAccounts[i]=!totalAccounts[i]" /> {{account.controls.accountName.value}}   
......

    <button type="submit" class="next" [disabled]="!(totalAccounts[0] && totalAccounts[1])">Next</button>
```

Comment: what does this part of code actually mean here
totalAccounts[i]=!totalAccounts[i]

Comment: Inverting its value, when it's true, new value would be false, and if it's false, the new value would be true

Comment: I have tried that but i find that when i click once it gets disabled even one check box is already checked

Comment: And i also need to click my checkbox twice to make it selected or de select it

Comment: Remove checked() to test please